How to highlight the next expression that matches the currently selected expression
Sometimes, one has to modify a notebook in multiple places that contain the same text.
Is there a way to highlight the next expression that matches the currently selected expression so one can edit all these places simultaneously?
For example, in Visual Studio Code, one can achieve this by using Ctrl+D or by Alt+J in Kate.
Is there a corresponding keyboard shortcut in Mathematica?

Did you try Find?

According to the documentation, Find finds only the first line in the input that contains the specific string. Moreover, it prints it to the output. I want to have these found phrases selected so I can edit all of them at once.

There is also "FindNext" (button F3).
